# Etherscan API : How can I download all transactions by block id?

Tags: ethereum, etherscan

I am exploring etherscan api. I would like a list of all transactions by block or date. But the api almost always requires address or topic to fetch the transaction. Is there a way to get all txs or all txs by block ?

Answer (score 0):

You do not EtherScan for this, you can get this

- [From any Ethereum JSON-RPC node](https://ethereumnodes.com)
- Any programming langauge
- [Using eth_getBlockByNumber](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/#eth_getblockbynumber) API

EtherScan is a commercial, private, data provider. This blockchain data is public and available on any node. Using a private service provider for such basic query is counterproductive.

Comment: what minimal time delay to get entire recent blocks using those APIs?

Comment: If you run a local node, the delay is zero because your node has the full Ethereum state. For commercial JSON-RPC node providers you need to test out.